# Grouping data within logs by IP apache

Tags: apache-2.2, linux

Is it possible to group the data within the logs by IP so that I can easily differenciate between local requests from requests via the internet. I'm using Linux so it would have to linux based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use webalizer. It is a good apache log file analyzer. 
& also has support various grouping options.

[webalizer site](http://www.webalizer.org/)

[webalizer at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webalizer)

Answer (score 0):

awk '{print $n}'   | sort | uniq -c 
This will give you good running numbers of requests by IP. And can be done without a load of logs into webalizer. Much fancier stuff is possible as well.

Get to know YOUR log file format and you can do all kinds of magic with it.
Also get to know your CLI tools for doing on the fly stuff. awk is a great one to start with to get a few basics under your belt and then move on to another tool.